# Is Hotaru really Nadeshiko?

Tags: unbreakable-machine-doll

Magnus (or Akabane big-brother) has one of her dolls shaped exactly like Raishin Akabane's sister: Nadeshiko.

The name of the puppet is Hotaru.

Was Hotaru made from Nadeshiko's body?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the entire squadron of Magnus is made up of the oragans of Nadeshiko. It was mentioned in volume 10 of the light novel, but I don't remember if it was mentioned much earlier in the novel. This is the line in volume 10: *"The doll of my enemy. She even had some of Nadeshiko’s organs inside her body" (仇の人形。まして、体内に撫子の部品を格納しているのだ。)*. It was stated in volume 1 that Nadeshiko's body was empty because Tenzen took the organs to create the Squadron.

> In volume 16, it was revealed that Hotaru has Nadeshiko's brain, Tamamushi has Nadeshiko's digestive organ, Kamakiri has Nadeshiko's sense organ, Kagerou has Nadeshiko's muscle fibre, Mitsubashi has Nadeshiko's heart and Himegumo has Nadeshiko's nervous system. Nadeshiko's organs were used to revive her (one of the two keys to her resurrection) and to keep her off the radar of the Izanagi clan's prophecy.

You can check out this [Fandom site](https://unbreakable-machine-doll.fandom.com/wiki/Unbreakable_Machine-Doll_Wiki).